# adding data to wcf rest service using jquery

Tags: jquery, rest

i have this on my rest service

```
public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
public List<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetails { get; set; }

public InvoiceGroup()
    {
        Invoices = new List<Invoice>();
        InvoiceDetails = new List<InvoiceDetail>();
    }
```

now, my question is how can i add data to it using jquery? any ideas? thank you.

**Update:** I am trying to create an invoice. so the invoice code will come from the invoices list and the items on the items would be stored on the details.

Comment: adding data means what ? or do you want to call this service by jquery ??

Comment: i want to call this service using jquery with a type "PUT" or "POST"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path to your service ../AddInvoiceGroup",
    data: jsonDTO,
    type: "POST",
    success: // on success whatever you want to do

    },
    error: function (xmlRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert("your error handling");
    }
});
```

**UPDATED**:
see i have done it by passing an object to the service like below and pass it as json string.

```
var DTO = { 'inv': invoiceObject};
var jsonDTO = JSON.stringify(DTO);

public AddInvoiceGroup(Invoice inv)
{
    //call a member which will do adding stuff
}
```

Comment: okay, i get that part of the code. the question is how would i add the invoice details and invoices part.

Comment: yes. but i'm still puzzled about this. i think i need to study more on the rest side. thank you though.